# Scala: Conditional For-Comprehension with Futures

Tags: scala, future, for-comprehension

I need a `for` comprehension that invokes *N* methods that return a `Future[Int]` and yield only odd numbers. The following code doesn't work because after the first even result the block returns a `Failure`:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def f1 = Future(1)
def f2 = Future(2)
def f3 = Future(3)
def f4 = Future(4)

for {
  i1 <- f1 if i1 % 2 != 0
  i2 <- f2 if i2 % 2 != 0
  i3 <- f3 if i3 % 2 != 0
  i4 <- f4 if i4 % 2 != 0
} yield ???
```

How do I get the following result?

```
List[Future(1), Future(3)]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can something like this work instead?

```
val futures = List(f1, f2, f3, f4)
Future.sequence(futures).map(_.filter(_ % 2 != 0))
```

the result is

```
List(1, 3)
```

Comment: Is it possible to avoid filtering? In my real use case the list might be quite long...

Comment: The compiler translates `if` conditions inside `for` comprehensions into a filter (actually `withFilter()`).